# Can you use a ruby @model.attribute for scss logic?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sass

This is the footer I currently have:

```
.footer.parfoot {
  background: asset_url('footer_flower.png'), #243966;
  background-position: 90% 100%;
  background-size: 140px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

I would like to switch out the asset_url with an image depending on what the model is. Ex: `asset_url (@partner.logo), #243966`

I don't believe this is possible but I figure there was another way.

I was thinking having multiple footers for each model(@partner) In the HAML file I could have logic to call the footer based off which model is present.

Like this?

```
- if @partner.present?
              =link_to url_with_protocol( @partner.website ) do
                = image_tag 'tulip-logo-white.webp', class: "logo ob-inline-block parlogo fotlog" rescue nil


%footer.footer.parfoot


else footer.footer.defaultfoot
```

Comment: I think you need to use `.scss.erb` extension and pass variables in through ERB calls. Unlike slim, scss doesn't directly support Ruby in that way

Comment: @maxpleaner its only Sprockets that passes assets though ERB. You can do it with webpacker but it involves installing and configuring the erb-loader plugin. Even as such its only really suitible for stuff thats known at deploy time like for example setting site wide settings from a Yaml file.

Answer (score 0):

Just define different css classes for each partner and 1 default:

```css
.footer {
  background-position: 90% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 140px;
}

.footer--default {
  background: asset_url('footer_default.png'), #243966;
}

.footer--flower {
  background: asset_url('footer_flower.png'), #243966;
}

.footer--gift {
  background: asset_url('footer_gift.png'), #243966;
}
```

Change HAML:

```
- if @partner.present?
  = link_to url_with_protocol(@partner.website) do
    = image_tag 'tulip-logo-white.webp', class: "logo ob-inline-block parlogo fotlog" rescue nil


%footer.footer{ class: "#{footer_class(@partner)}"}
```

And add code to `application_helper.rb`:

```rb
def footer_class(partner)
  return 'footer--default' if partner.blank?

  case partner.logo
  when 'flower'
    'footer--flower'
  when 'gift'
    'footer--gift'
  else
    'footer--default'
  end
end
```

Comment: This would work if the potential list of images is known at deploy time and adding them is a developer concern.

Answer (score 0):

#### Big Nope

Dynamically generating CSS/JS assets per request is not a thing - Rails does this in development simply as a convenience.

In Rails assets are compiled at deploy time in production and are not request aware even in development. Thus the whole idea of replacing values in a SCSS file based on a model that is fetched per request is broken.

You should additionally consider that you want to deploy a single CSS file for all visitors and push it out into CDNs, reverse proxies and edge caches for performance and serve the same assets to all visitors.

Instead you can use element styles (inline CSS) to set the background image:

```
module PartnersHelper
  def partner_footer(partner)
    if partner 
      "background-image: url('#{image_path(@partner.logo)}')"
    else
      "background-image: url('#{image_path('footer_flower.png')}')"
    end
  end
end
```

```
%footer.footer.parfoot {
  style: partner_footer(@partner)
}
```

I know that you might be saying "But inline CSS is EVIL!" - not always. Its perfectly fine when you are applying a unique style to particular elements.

Also instead of making your Haml files into a huge if/else tree use [content_for](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-the-content-for-method) to inject content:

```
# app/views/layouts/application.html.haml
= content_for :footer 
  %h3 This is the default content
```

```
# app/views/partners/show.html.haml
= content_for :footer 
  = link_to url_with_protocol( @partner.website ) do
    # NEVER use rescue nil!
    = image_tag 'tulip-logo-white.webp', 
                class: "logo ob-inline-block parlogo fotlog"
```

It concatenates by default but you can replace the contents with the `flush: true` option.

Comment: Thank you Max. This was a code base I took over, and this looks like it'll do the trick.